# Android Studio Warning: Missing density variation folders in 'src\main\res': drawable-xxxhdpi

Tags: android, warnings

In Android Studio, after using *Analyze* >> *Inspect Code...*, I got following warning: Missing density variation folders in 'src\main\res': drawable-xxxhdpi

But by default, there is no such a folder after creating an empty project.

How to fix it?

Comment: yes. you should create this manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this warning not just because some folder is missing, but because it is recommended to create density-specific graphics in your projects. In your case, you don't have graphics for `xxxhdpi` density, and Android Studio reminds you of that. Create this folder manually inside `res` folder, just where the regular `drawable` folder is.

More on density specific graphics in [Supporting Multiple Screens](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

Comment: Thank you :)
After I created the directory drawable-xxxhdpi under res, I ran Inspect Code... again, this time is another warning, saying add all the corresponding graphics under drawable-xxxhdpi, after adding all 144px*144px icons, there is no more warning.
But I am wondering why Android Studio doesn't create the drawable-xxxhdpi by default so there would be no this warning?

Comment: The documentation says: "You do not need to provide xxxhdpi assets for all your app's images." Why should I create an `xxxhdpi` folder then?